# Exception error while doing google sign-in in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I have implemented the google-sign-in functionality as follows :

```
void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    // Detects when user signed in
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print('Error Signing in : $err');
    });
    // Reauthenticate user when the app is opened(/reopened)
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
        handleSignIn(account);
      }).catchError((err) {
        print('Error Signing in : $err');
      });
  }

  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if(account!=null){
        print('User signed in! : $account');
        setState(() {
          isAuth = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isAuth = true;
        });
      }
  }
```

I have done the proper error handling with catchError still it's giving me the following error :

> flutter: Error Signing in : PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.GIDSignIn, The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.))

on the line :

```
googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false)
```

Any hint where I am doing wrong ?